# How to remap graphics card color palette to negative colors

Tags: color-scheme, color-palette, magnify

I want to set my windows color scheme to negative colors. I tried to use Magnify tool  which can be used to make negative colors scheme. But this program generates some lag. It is especially visible when moving mouse. I am now searching for new way to make negative color scheme. I think that the fastest way will be to remap graphics card color palette. It should not generate such lag like I'm now experiencing. Can someone give me a tip how can i do it programmatically (preferred c# but i don't think that it is be possible to do in higher level language)? Or maybe there is already some kind of tool to do that (I have Intel GMA HD)?
I have already tried NegativeScreen software (http://arcanesanctum.net/negativescreen) but it have even bigger lag.

Comment: I found that Powerstrip has that functionality "invert gamma ramp". Unfortunately it does not work on my Intel HD graphics card